# INVALID_ARGUMENT: Role roles/youtube.fullAccess is not supported for this resource

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I'am trying to add a list of YouTube video links to my personal YouTube playlist from the gcloud terminal on my Windows machine. I logged in using the standard command `gcloud auth application-default login`, which automatically retrieved my access token from https://cloud.google.com/sdk/auth_success?hl=it.

The account email I used for logging in is `aaabbb@gmail.com`, which is linked to my YouTube account and is the same one I used to create the project on Google Cloud. The name of the project is `playlistyoutube-384311`.

However, I'm having trouble adding the video links to my playlist. I've followed the necessary steps, but I keep getting an "`insufficient permission`" error. I've checked my account and project permissions and they seem to be correct. 
Can you help me figure out what's wrong and how to fix it?

To do this operation I try to do using this python script

```
import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# Authentication with Google
creds, project = google.auth.default(
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl']
)

# Create an instance of the YouTube service
youtube_service = build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=creds)

# ID of the playlist to edit
playlist_id = 'PLNpx7L8t1Ikm41ZahIv7JpW0DlPmJe_Ky'

# Example: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNpx7L8t1Ikm41ZahIv7JpW0DlPmJe_Ky
# The playlist ID is the last element of the URL in this case "PLNpx7L8t1Ikm41ZahIv7JpW0DlPmJe_Ky"

# List of video IDs to add to playlist
video_ids = ['jZcLBeba6eY', 'WYp9Eo9T3BA', 'jZ2mQqMCt_c']

# Add each video to the playlist
for video_id in video_ids:
    try:
        # Add the video to the playlist
        add_video_request = youtube_service.playlistItems().insert(
            part="snippet",
            body={
              "snippet": {
                "playlistId": playlist_id,
                "position": 0,
                "resourceId": {
                  "kind": "youtube#video",
                  "videoId": video_id
                }
              }
            }
        )
        response = add_video_request.execute()

        # Print the ID of the video you just added to the playlist
        print(f'Added video with ID "{video_id}" to the playlist with ID "{playlist_id}"')
    except HttpError as error:
        print(f'Error adding video with ID "{video_id}" to the playlist with ID "{playlist_id}": {error}')
```

But I get this error

```
PS C:\Users\stage.catalogo\Desktop\python\scaricare lista di link youtube da una lista> python modificare_playlist.py
Error adding video with ID "jZcLBeba6eY" to playlist with ID "PLNpx7L8t1Ikm41ZahIv7JpW0DlPmJe_Ky": <HttpError 403 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'message': 'Insufficient Permission', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions'}]">
Error adding video with ID "WYp9Eo9T3BA" to playlist with ID "PLNpx7L8t1Ikm41ZahIv7JpW0DlPmJe_Ky": <HttpError 403 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'message': 'Insufficient Permission', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions'}]">
.....
```

I tried to check permissions

```
gcloud auth list

Credentialed Accounts

ACTIVE: *
ACCOUNT: aaabbb@gmail.com

ACTIVE:
ACCOUNT: playlist@playlistyoutube-384311.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

I tried

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy playlistyoutube-384311
```

output

```
bindings:
- members:
  - deleted:serviceAccount:playlist@playlistyoutube-384311.iam.gserviceaccount.com?uid=104362102214175217625
  role: roles/editor
- members:
  - deleted:serviceAccount:playlist@playlistyoutube-384311.iam.gserviceaccount.com?uid=104362102214175217625
  - user:aaabbb@gmail.com
  role: roles/owner
etag: BwX51hZphUI=
version: 1
```

I tried to add youtube.fullAccess role but without success

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding playlistyoutube-384311 --member=user:aaabbb@gmail.com --role=roles/youtube.fullAccess
```

it returns me this error

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT: Role roles/youtube.fullAccess is not supported for this resource
```